# ReactJS Redux Toolkit - Fetching data from an API based on an Id does not get the second Id if called again

Tags: reactjs, redux, toolkit

I am use ReactJS and Redux Toolkit (not using RTK Query). I setup a slice to retrieve data from an API based on an Id. The first time I fetch the data everything works fine. If I try to fetch data for a different Id nothing is fetched as it appears it just returns what is there. Am I using redux incorrectly or am I missing something easy. Below is the code. Further more, I would like to use the same piece of the store for different data types but the data is shaped the same. So the API call would be different but the data put in the store is shaped the same.

```
export const getScoreData = createAsyncThunk(
    'contentitem/scoredata',
    async (params) => {
        return axios.get(`${params.apiAddress}api/v2/scores/${params.scoreId}`)
            .then(
                res => res.data,
                err => console.error(err)
            );
    }
);

export const scoreSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'contentitem',
    initialState,
    reducers: {},
    extraReducers: {
        [getScoreData.pending]: (state) => {
            state.loading = true;
            state.complete = false;
        },
        [getScoreData.fulfilled]: (state, { payload }) => {
            state.loading = false;
            state.complete = true;
            state.data = payload;
        },
        [getScoreData.rejected]: (state) => {
            state.loading = false;
            state.complete = true;
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry all, it was not the redux toolkit or the store it was how I was interacting with it in my react components. Problem solved by calling the dispatch at the appropriate times.